# Swagger API console not working in WSO2

Tags: java, wso2, swagger, swagger-ui, wso2-api-manager

I am working on WSO2API Manager 1.7.0 , I have published APIs but I was not able to call it from the API Store in the API Console section via Swagger ,  it is not passing the Authorization parameters and the call is always being rejected from the API Manager in the OAuthenticator  saying that the key is null  , although the header is specified in the UI, even with the sample API of the youtube I was not able to make one successful call through API Console.

[image: API Manager refusing the call because the authorization header was not passed]

[image: Invoking the API from swagger and passing the authorization details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable CORS configuration in the api-manager.xml. And if you use IP address there to indicate "access allow origin parameters" you should use IP address to access api-store portal.

Comment: do we need to always specify the IP addresses is it ok if we used hostanmes , it seems not.

Comment: if you use hostname at the configuration, use hostname to access the store portal

Comment: I am still not able to post a JSON body to one of my apis the problem appears again , can i upgrade swagger-ui in the store it is really unstable and it is losing a lot of functionalities offered by swagger ui

Comment: We upgrade the swagger in store in our next release You can expect it in first week of September. upgrading swagger in 1.7.0 requires some code level changes.

Comment: thanks I am really looking forward to it , I am really having a problem with posting any JSON data to my backed service always being rejected